# How to configure Nginx autoindex to edit files?

Tags: file, nginx, editor, nginx-config

I have configured Nginx with autoindex module to enable Directory Listing. But I want to extend this feature to enable file editing as well and saving it.

The thing is I have some Private IPs which needs to be monitored and I have added those IPs in a file and made a script to take IPs from the file and monitor them by Pinging. Since sometimes these IPs change due to DHCP, Apart from System Admins, No one is much proficient in using Terminal. Hence I wanted to provide a webUI, so that concerned persons change this IP whenever through webpage. I know this can be possible using code, but since am not a developer, I was finding a way through here. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible using nginx alone.